# Commit new value from itemEditor before itemEditEnd event

Tags: apache-flex, itemeditor

I have a DataGrid, with `itemEditor` as `NumericStepper` in a few columns. When a value in the DataGrid is edited, I would like to update several values displayed on the screen, and so want to call a `updateValues()` function.

First, I added this function to `itemEditEnd` event of the `DataGrid`, but the function is getting called before the new value is updated into the `dataProvider` and hence, the values I have in the function are the old values. Is there any other event that is fired after the values are updated into the `dataProvider`? or am I missing something?

Second, I tried putting this function in the change event of each `itemEditor` (duh!), but then again, the change event is fired, but the values in the `dataProvider` are the old ones.

Is there any way I can make the function `updateValues()` be called, every time a value is edited AND updated into the `dataProvider`, because there's where I am taking the values from?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "In your event listener, you can examine the data entered into the item editor. If the data is incorrect, you can call the preventDefault() method to stop Flex from passing the new data back to the list-based control and from closing the editor." ([source](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=celleditor_7.html))

So yeah, it gets called before the dataprovider has the data.

Here's what you should read: [Detecting Datagrid Edits](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/detecting_datagrid_edits.html). He talks about all the same stuff. Event priority is the ticket. Overly complicated is the Flex way. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Glenn, I'll check the link and get back :)

Comment: how can I do the "you can examine the data entered into the item editor" part.. may be I can get the value I want in that way?

Comment: In the "Accessing cell data and the item editor in an event listener" section of my first link, look at the "getCellInfo" function.

Comment: Glenn, I love you! That is exactly what I needed, though it took some time, I am finally finished with the datagrid.
THANKS a lot!