# Is there any event like itemEditEnding or any other way to stop event before itemEditEnd event in datagrids of Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have editable grids which are 2-way binded to my model. What I want is to validate my data when user edits any cell before it get updated in model. I have applied my validation at ItemEditEnd handler, but, I want to apply validation in between itemEditBegin and itemEditEnd events.

any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

For this level of validation I would create a Validator for the type of data you're editing (string, number, etc.) and set the Validator's trigger to the change event of your itemEditor component.

Check out [Adobe's example](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=celleditor_8.html) on using validators in an itemEditor for more info.

**Update:**

You may also want to check out [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388063/commit-new-value-from-itemeditor-before-itemeditend-event).

> "In your event listener, you can
>   examine the data entered into the item
>   editor. If the data is incorrect, you
>   can call the preventDefault() method
>   to stop Flex from passing the new data
>   back to the list-based control and
>   from closing the editor."